# Ошибка Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу,

Tags: c#

Ошибка Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, т.к. этот файл используется другим процессом. 
Что мне нужно, разработать класс файл, предусмотреть возможность добавления в его конец.
Собственно это код с Form.

```
     if (match.Success)
                ;
            else
                throw new IOException(" Неверный формат имени файла.");

            File file1 = new File(file_Name, text);
            file1.Add(file_Name, text);          
            file1.get_Info(textBox1);
            ...
            catch (Exception ex)// 
            тут ошибка, если обработку оставить
```

Теперь класс File

```
  public File (string f_Name, string info)
        if (f_Name != null && info != null)
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(f_Name))
                FileInfo exist_File = new FileInfo(f_Name);
                //Заполняем поля
            else
                System.IO.File.Create(f_Name);
                FileInfo create_File = new FileInfo(f_Name);
                //Заполняем поля
```

Вот тут, что выше у меня некоторые проблемы с логикой программы, заодно тут можно подсказать.

```
        public void Add(string f_name,string new_text)
    {
        ошибка тут, если без try ... catch
        using (StreamWriter f_Stream = new StreamWriter(f_name, true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {
            byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(new_text);
            //int temp_Length = Convert.ToInt32(Length);
            //Length += array.Length;
            f_Stream.Write(new_text);
            Information += Environment.NewLine + new_text;
```

Что не так: 
1) Если файл с таким именем не создан, возникает ошибка(смотри шапку), но файл создаётся, добавление в него возможно(с другого button'a).
2) Если файл уже имеется, то всё хорошо, мы добавляем строку в конец файла и выводим информацию по нему.

В чём косяк?

Comment: Косяк, вероятнее всего в вашем классе File (вообще делать собственный класс, который называется точно также как библиотечный - это скверный стиль написания, такое надо исключать) вы в конструкторе где-то создаете ссылку на файл и тем самым держите его открытым, что не дает методу Add работать с файлом. И зачем, нужна эта проверка в конструкторе, если в библиотечном классе уже есть опции OpenCreate и проч.?

Comment: @Bulson Вы хотели сказать "Ошибка проектирования" вместо слова "косяк", верно?

Comment: Проверка Exist()?  Можно пальцем ткнуть, что OpenCreate'ом заменить

Comment: @AK я сказал то, что хотел сказать. Вопрос был с со словом "косяк", я отвечал с использованием терминологии автора вопроса.

Comment: `System.IO.File.Create` создаёт файл и возвращает файловый поток - `FileStream` - вот пока он не закрыт, доступа больше нет.

Comment: @Алексей [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: Т.е в потоке мы создадим файл, и между записью и чтением он будет доступен другим процесса, а во время записи нет? А разве StreamWriter не создаёт сам поток?

Comment: Вы открываете файл только тогда, когда вам действительно нужно в него записать или прочитать, после этого вы его сразу должны  закрыть. Это всё.

Comment: Всем спасибо. По вашим советам переделаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одном месте кода у вас вызывается

```
System.IO.File.Create(f_Name);
```

— этот метод создаёт файл, открывает его и возвращает файловый поток `FileStream`. Пока этот поток не закрыт - файл занят.

В другом месте кода у вас используется

```
new StreamWriter(f_name, ...);
```

— попытка открыть и использовать тот же файл, судя по всему. Естественно, это приводит к ошибке.

Что можно сделать?

1. Закрывать поток сразу после создания файла:

   ```
   System.IO.File.Create(f_Name).Close();
   ```

   Решение рабочее, хотя и странное: зачем открывать файл и тут же его закрывать.
2. Сохранять ссылку на созданный файловый поток и далее использовать её вместо имени файла:

   ```
   // Поле класса
   FileStream fileStream;
   ```

   Обратите внимание: это именно *поле* класса, не *локальная* переменная.

   ```
   // Сохраняем ссылку на файловый поток
   fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(f_Name);
   ```

   В другом месте (методе) кода:

   ```
   // Используем поток вместо строкового имени файла
   new StreamWriter(fileStream);
   ```

   Это должно работать.

   Важно: при таком подходе обязательно реализуйте в своём классе интерфейс `IDisposable`, в `Dispose` методе которого *обязательно* должен закрываться этот файловый поток.
3. Вместо `System.IO.File.Create` использовать конструктор

   ```
   new FileStream(...);
   ```

   У него целых 15 перегрузок со множеством всевозможных параметров: `FileMode`, `FileAccess` и другие. Нас сейчас интересует `FileShare`.

   При создании файлового потока можно указать, разрешаем ли мы доступ другим процессам к нему:

   ```
   new FileStream(f_Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
   ```

   Тут мы указали, что создаём (`Create`) новый файл, получаем к нему доступ (`Write`) на чтение и разрешаем - `Share` - другим процессам писать (`Write`) в него.

   Теперь в любом другом участке кода мы можем получить доступ к этому файлу, воспользовавшись конструктором с нужными параметрами:

   ```
   using (var fs = new FileStream(f_Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
   {
   }
   ```

   Тут мы открываем (`Open`) поток с доступом на запись и разрешением на запись (`Write`). Таким образом, в системе может быть несколько указателей на открытый файл, но у них у всех должны быть одинаковые параметры на доступ.

   При этом открыть его на чтение не получится, т. к. изначально это было не разрешено. Поэтому выбирайте нужное вам сочетание параметров.

   Хотя, конечно, второй способ - с хранением ссылки на открытый файл - правильнее.