# Чтение и запись в файл с помощью BlockingCollection

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

---

У меня есть класс который производит чтение и запись в файл, но периодически появляется исключение о том что данный файл занят другим потоком.

Я хотел бы построить функцию записи и чтения с помощью **BlockingCollection**. Нужно открыть задачу записи и ждать пока в очереди не появятся данные на запись, но так же иметь возможность читать любые данные с этого же файла.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении данной задачи!

---

Для полного представления приведу 2 примера кода:

Первый нужно переделать с использованием BlockingCollection

```cs
static class Setting
    {
        private static string FileDirectory = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        private static string FileCatalog = "bin/account/";
        private static string FileName = "setting.elum";


        public static async Task<bool> Write()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists((FileDirectory.Remove(FileDirectory.Length - Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Length)) + FileCatalog))
                {
                    CreateDirectory(FileCatalog);
                }

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Global.globalBinding);
                if(json != null)
                {
                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.WriteAllText(FileCatalog + FileName, json, Encoding.UTF8));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
        }


        public static async Task<bool> Read()
        {

            string dir = FileCatalog + FileName;
            try
            {

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dir))
                {
                    await Write();
                }

                using (var reader = File.OpenText(dir))
                {
                    var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    if (json != "")
                    {
                        var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalBinding>(json);
                        Global.globalBinding = a;
                        if(Global.globalBinding == a)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var a = await Write();
                        if(a != false)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                return true;
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }

        private static void CreateDirectory(string pach)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pach);
        }


    }
```

А второй работает но только на запись

```cs
    internal static class log
    {

        private static string _fileDirectory = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        private static string _fileCatalog = "bin/logout/";
        private static string _fileName = "log.elum";

        private static BlockingCollection<string> _blockingCollection;

        private static Task _task;

        static log()
        {
            _fileDirectory = _fileDirectory.Remove(_fileDirectory.Length - 8) + _fileCatalog;
            _blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

            // Проверка существования директории
            if (!Directory.Exists(_fileDirectory))
            {
                CreateDirectory(_fileDirectory);
            }

            // Задача для записи  в файл
            _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileDirectory + _fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;

                    foreach (var s in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(s);
                }
            },
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }

        // Добавление в очередь на запись в файл
        public static void WriteLog(string action, string errorDiscription, int errorCode = 0)
        {
            _blockingCollection.Add($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")} действие: {action}, код: {errorCode.ToString()}, описание: { errorDiscription} ");
        }

        //Создание отсутствующей директории
        private static void CreateDirectory(string pach)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pach);
        }

        // выключение записи из очереди
        public static void Flush()
        {
            _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
            _task.Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: сделайте кеш в памяти, читайте из кеша (это и быстрее будет), пишите в файл и одновременно с этим обновляйте кеш. Тогда вам не понадобятся никакие коллекции, максимум - ReaderWriterLock - для одного писателя (в файл и в кеш) и многих читателей.

Comment: Перезаписываемая информация может быть достаточно большой. Это файл полностью всех настроек приложения. Положение чек боксов, цвета кнопок и множество разных настроек. Чтение и запись в файл нужна только при запуске приложения и сохранения настроек. Хранить все время в кэше кучу этих данных будет не совсем рационально.

Comment: достаточно большой это сколько? 100 мегабайт - это много, 5 мегабайт - это ерунда. К тому же, если это настройки, то вы уже храните их в памяти. Или вы каждый раз, когда надо получить настройки, считываете весь файл в память? Если у вас запись идет только когда юзер созраняет настройки, то тут в принципе нечего синхронизировать, юзер не может созранять настройки и читать их параллельно.

Comment: Все верно. Проблема не в одновременном чтении и записи а в одновременной записи в файл.
Все параметры хранятся в отдельном классе с переменными к которому прикручен Binding чтение происходит один раз а в дальнейшем пользователь изменяет настройки и нажимает сохранить все обновленные переменные перезаписываются в файле... но если пользователь быстро исправил один из параметров и нажал сохранить опять то мне приходит ошибка о том что файл уже занят другим процессом

Comment: ну так вы кнопку "сохранить" блокируйте, пока идет сохранение и все дела.

Comment: Как вариант можно добавить кнопку "Сохранить" и блокировать ее. Но тогда время сохранения будет длительным из за того что открытие файла занимает большое время. А так я открыл бы поток на запись и чтение и он бы висел до того момента пока не понадобился. Вообщем это я уже сильно придираюсь =) сделаю через блокировку кнопки) Большое Вам спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Я бы также посоветовал приглядеться к тому, что именно тормозит при записи в файл. Само открытие файла на запись занимает не сильно много времени. Но, например, если вы пишете мелкими порциями в файл (например, построчно), то это будет гораздо медленней, чем запись в файл с буфером([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947151/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848376/179763)) , если же вы просто пишете сериализованные объекты - возможно, сериализация ваше узкое место.

Comment: Я переписываю весь файл чтобы не тратить время на поиски измененных данных. `File.WriteAllText(FileCatalog + FileName, json, Encoding.UTF8)`

Comment: на всякий случай добавьте логгирование или замерьте, сколько занимает сериализация и сколько сама запись, чтобы понять, что именно тормозит у вас.

Comment: Запись в файл вместе с сериализацией занимает 9ms

Comment: тогда что тормозит то? за 9ms юзер не вспеет второй раз нажать кнопку "сохранить"

Comment: Да если это не горячая клавиша. Я ее зажимаю и все) Вообщем поставлю блокировку до того момента пока не пройдет запись.

Comment: а, ну с этого надо было начинать :)

Comment: У вас есть логгер, который в цикле ждёт поступление новых сообщений и записывает их в файл. **Всю** запись в файл делайте через него. И не будет проблем.

Comment: Если у вас файл занят (другим) процессом, то, вероятно, нужно задать уровни доступа к нему. Параметры `FileMode`, `FileAccess`, `FileShare`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670623/184217

Comment: loger свой я привел в пример для того чтобы показать что я хочу от записи в Setting но с дополнительной возможностью читать из потока. Вообщем Я создал переменную определяющую происходит в данный момент запись в файл или нет. с помощью нее я определяю можно ли выполнить действие в данный момент. В итоге все что может затронуть процесс записи будет ждать ее окончания. И никаких циклов. Суть вопроса была вообще -  то про создания записи и чтения через BlockingCollection. Всем большое спасибо за участие в решении моей проблемы!